# Let  be a Log-Normally distributed RV with  = 3 and  = 2. Determine  (100 ≤  ≤ 150)

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution

I do not get how $\Phi\left(\frac{\ln (100)-3}{2}\right)$ and $\Phi\left(\frac{\ln (150)-3}{2}\right)$ should give me the probabilities 0.7889 and 0.8426 respectively.
I looked at the distribution table and used a calculator but I get different results.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I don't think this question needs a complete solution. The OP clearly states what he/she has done. It just needs the right direction.